# How to handle ERROR while Populating document With Mongoose 6.6.3 and Next js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

So I populate game from the product like this

```
    const getHandler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
        await db.connect();
        const products = await Product.find({}).populate('game')
                .populate('category'); 
        res.send(products);
        await db.disconnect();
    };
```

Its works but sometimes I get an error like this

> MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Game". Use mongoose.model(name, schema)

And I assume  that this is because I have to call the model first, in my populate code  like this

```
const games = await Game.find({});
//calling the model
            const category = await Category.find({});
            const products = await Product.find({})
                .populate('game', 'status')
                .populate('category', 'name');
```

after this, I never get an error again, Is there any better way to handle this error?

Comment: I would guess that the problem is that you've never imported `Game` anywhere. Simply importing it should work IMO

Comment: i have imported both game and category like this 
 ```if (method === 'GET') {
  try {
   await db.connect();
   const game = await Games.find({
    status: 'Y',
   });
   res.status(201).json(game);```